# Searching multiple fields at ounce in Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to search multiple fields in my Firebase database for app users to lookup contacts with FirstName, LastName, and JobTitle. I know that queries with "OR" is one of the limitations, but I was wondering if someone came up with a way to merge multiple queries to substitute the functionality of "OR". Below is the code I am using to search users based on their first name.

Thanks Folks!

```
  final usersProfile = Firestore.instance.collection('Users');
  handleSearch(String query) {
    Future<QuerySnapshot> users =
        usersProfile.where('First Name', isEqualTo: query).getDocuments();
    setState(() {
      searchResultsFuture = users;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, you can certainly make multiple queries and collect all of their results into some sort of a list.  It doesn't look like you've made an attempt to do that yet.

Comment: I tried several things but non of them worked. If you know how it could be done please let me share your code with me.